# TKenv in omnet++ cannot run

Tags: ubuntu, simulation, omnet++

i installed omnet++ on my ubuntu 15.10

i am trying to run omnetpp.ini on TKenv simulator but it gave an error i don't know what it is.

this is the error

Error during startup: Could not start user interface 'Tkenv'.
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2014 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 4.6, build: 141202-f785492, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer

User interface 'Tkenv' not found (not linked in or loaded dynamically).
Available ones are:
  Cmdenv : command-line user interface

End.
Starting...

$ cd /home/ibrahim/Downloads/omnetpp-4.6/samples/ijij/Simulations/radioTest
$ ../../ijij -r 0 -u Tkenv -n ..:../../src omnetpp.ini

Simulation terminated with exit code: 1
Working directory: /home/ibrahim/Downloads/omnetpp-4.6/samples/ijij/Simulations/radioTest
Command line: ../../ijij -r 0 -u Tkenv -n ..:../../src omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:
PATH=/home/ibrahim/Downloads/omnetpp-4.6/bin::/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ibrahim/Downloads/omnetpp-4.6/lib::
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=/home/ibrahim/Downloads/omnetpp-4.6/images

please help me.

[[error screen shot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8k5h.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8k5h.png)

Answer (score 2):

The `Castalia` project by default uses `Cmdenv` mode only. In order to run simulation in `Tkenv` open `makemake` file (from root directory) in a text editor and add `-u Tkenv` to the `OPTS` variable. As a consequence, this line should look like:

```
OPTS=" -f -r --deep -o CastaliaBin -u Cmdenv -u Tkenv -P $ROOT -M release"
```

Next, open Ubuntu terminal, go to root directory of the `Castalia` project and type `./makemake`. (This has to be done every time after changing of `makemake` file.) Then type: `make clean && make`.

Comment: thank you but it didn't work keeps turning the same error, is there any else solution ?

Comment: The script `makemake` has to be once executed after modification. I have just extended my answer.

Comment: still got the same error , i am sorry for that but i hope to solve it

Comment: Type the following commands: `./makemake`, `make clean`, `make`.

Comment: By the way, I suggest you editing your question and adding the name of project (e.g. Castalia) and error message (as text). Without these elements the usability of your question for SO users is low.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is based on this line: User interface 'Tkenv' not found (not linked in or loaded dynamically). Available ones are: Cmdenv : command-line user interface.

This means that OMNeT++ itself was built without Tk support. Follow carefully the Installation guide. It specifies exactly what pakages you should install before running the `./configure`. It's most likely that you have not installed the development Tk and Tcl packages.

Hint: watch the output of the `./configure` command closely. It prints out whether Tk was correctly detected or not.